# How to change language in select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

i'm using select2 in v4.0.3

I want to change the default language from English to Spanish. Check the documentation in the internationalization section, but, as indicated, it has not worked for me.

I am attentive to your comments anex code

```js
$("#multisearch").select2({
        language: "es",
        closeOnSelect: false,
        placeholder: "Comienza tu búsqueda",
      data: [
       { 
        id: 0, 
        text: 'Linea 1',
              children: 
              [{
                   id: 1,
                   text: 'San Pablo'
                },
                {
                   id: 2,
                   text: 'Pajaritos'
                
                },
                {
                 id: 3,
                 text: 'Las Rejas'
                },
                {
                 id: 4,
                 text: 'Ecuador'
                }]
               },
               { 
        id: 5, 
        text: 'Linea 2',
              children: 
              [{
                   id: 6,
                   text: 'La Cisterna'
                },
                {
                   id: 7,
                   text: 'El Parrón'
                
                },
                {
                 id: 8,
                 text: 'Lo Ovalle'
                },
                {
                 id: 9,
                 text: 'Ciudad del niño'
                },
                {
                 id: 10,
                 text: 'Pajaritos'
                }
                ]
               },
             { id: 1, text: 'prueba' }, 
      ]});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>


<select multiple id="multisearch" style="width:500px">
</select>
```

I will be attentive, thank you very much

Comment: This question have an solution for your problem "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35816137/set-language-not-working-select2 "

Answer (score -1):

```js
$("#multisearch").select2({ language: "es", closeOnSelect: false, placeholder: "Comienza tu búsqueda", data: [ { id: 0, text: 'Linea 1', children: [{ id: 1, text: 'San Pablo' }, { id: 2, text: 'Pajaritos' }, { id: 3, text: 'Las Rejas' }, { id: 4, text: 'Ecuador' }] }, { id: 5, text: 'Linea 2', children: [{ id: 6, text: 'La Cisterna' }, { id: 7, text: 'El Parrón' }, { id: 8, text: 'Lo Ovalle' }, { id: 9, text: 'Ciudad del niño' }, { id: 10, text: 'Pajaritos' } ] }, { id: 1, text: 'prueba' }, ]});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>


<select multiple id="multisearch" style="width:500px">
</select>
```

Comment: it is jquery issues you have to put this https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js intead of http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js